# jQuery progressbar only load on first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I run my code it makes the animation not show on my progressbar and the percentages keep going up and dont stop at the given value.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong in my scripting or maybe namegiving. I try to make all progress bars load up to their given value as an animation with a span under them showing how much percent the progressbar is on.

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2s2bmoj2/

Ans some of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Result test</title>

    <!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.5/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Result page test</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>Result random test</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 js--wp-2">
                    <h2>Photoshop</h2>
                    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
                    <progress class="progressbar" value="21" max="100">
                    </progress>
                    <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
                    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
                    <progress class="progressbar" value="56" max="100">
                    </progress>
                    <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
                    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
                    <progress class="progressbar" value="83" max="100">
                    </progress>
                    <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
                    <h4>Kanalen</h4>
                    <progress class="progressbar" value="15" max="100">
                    </progress>
                    <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="index.html" class="js--wp-1">View open tests</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/animation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/progressbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

ANIMATION

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var progressbar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar')
        , target = +progressbar.value
        , time = (300 / target) * 5
        , value = 0;

    var loading = function () {
        value += 1;
        progressbar.value = value;

        $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

        if (value == target) {
            clearInterval(animate);
        }
    };
    var animate = setInterval(function () {
        loading();
    }, time);
});
```

Comment: The 'given value' is null, because you are testing if the value is `==` to `target`, but `target` is equal to `+progressbar.value`, and that is null, since you can't get value of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery code should be working. I created it in your codepen.

```
$(function() {  
  $.each($('progress'), function(key, item) {
    var targetVal = item.value;
    var currentVal = 0;
    var time =  (300 / targetVal) * 5;
    var progressText = $(item).next('[class^=progress-value]');
    item.value = 0;

    var loading = setInterval(function() {
      item.value = currentVal++;
      progressText.html(item.value + '%');

      if (targetVal == currentVal) {
        clearInterval(loading);
      }
    }, time);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use var prbar=getElementsByClassName('progressbar');

Comment: It keeps loading all bars infinite